# Client side javascript equivalent to Lucene

Tags: javascript, lucene

I was wondering if there's a Javascript equivalent to the Lucene API, designed to be used on client side to index a relatively small data set.

An example use case would be a static site (generated for instance) with the ability to search content without server side processing.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this : http://lunrjs.com/ It looks like what I'm searching for but doesn't seem to support fuzzy searches.

Comment: What do you mean by fuzzy search?

Comment: @OliverNightingale fuzzy search is about finding results despite a typos. IMHO it is a must-have feature for every decent search technology.

Comment: lunr.js has this to some extent, by using stemming and doing prefix searching, but it is almost definitely less able than Lucene in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, you could use [Search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index) in conjunction with [node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) or another similar hack. Practically, I doubt this effort is worth pursuing.

Answer (score 0):

You also have search-index as @mindas mentions. Lunr is more mature, and easier to get up and runnig, but search-index is maybe more feature rich? As with lunr, you'll need to do stemming on the data you want to index and/or use the matcher. The [matcher](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index/blob/master/doc/autosuggest.md) does prefix search and returns words and/or phrases that is present in your document index.

I'm biased, but I think it's now wort the effort to use search-index. [There are now some examples on how to use it client side with browserify.](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index/blob/master/doc/EXAMPLES.md)