# HTML / Javascript only recursive search?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I posted on a wishlist of a JS library that I wish their documentation search included results from more than just the titles of the pages. After I posted I realized that that may be difficult since when users download it from Github and use the docs on their local machine there is no server side code that will run such as PHP that could traverse the filesystem and parse all the results into an array, but before I just assume that there isn't a way to do it I thought I would ask.

When you look at this link: http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene

If you type in anything that isn't part of the list on the left, it won't show up, such as if you type in `goal` nothing shows even though in the first sentence it says `The goal of this section`. Is there a way to put together a JS search that would traverse all the files that are on the list put the text into an array that could be searched without server side code?

I know Jquery would probably make the job easier, but I doubt he would include that in his repository, so as plain vanilla JS as possible would be preferred.

Comment: Javascript does not generally have access to the file system. You would need some server side code, if not actively doing the search, at least to perform an indexing of the content to build out a structure that could be searched with JavaScript.

Comment: That particular filter on threejs.org is for filtering the docs on name, not the content of the docs themselves. That would be perfectly feasible to do, provided all of the content is loaded in memory, or via AJAX, using includes().

Comment: It's definitely possible, but would get really slow. You'd have to make an ajax request for every page, wait for them all to finish, and then write all the search logic in javascript, which will most definitely be slower than any server side language...

Comment: Client-side searches of filesystem artifacts depends on there being an index of some sort. Without that you're pretty much doomed.

Comment: @DaveNewton Looking at the source, there is a `list.js` which has an array of objects with the names and directories of all the files that are available.

Comment: @Alan Right, and that's how it does the search. What we're saying is that  unless you build an index of *content* there's nothing you can do. Could you? Possibly, if it lets you download those files via Ajax. Then you have to decide how and what to index, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/23058056/438992. Is it worth it? I doubt it--unless a content index is shipped you're looking at an expensive process.